# Removing All Traces of Primary Email Address When Using an Alias in Gmail API

Tags: python, email, google-api, gmail-api, google-oauth

I'm using the Google GMail API to send emails. All works as expected but I'm unable to specify an alias address as the sender such that the alias address is reflected completely throughout the email metadata.

For example:

Account Primary Email: `primary@example.com`
Account Alias Email: `alias@example.com`

When I send an email (having authenticated via oAuth using the primary account address) I can change the `from` and `reply-to` headers to reflect the `alias@example.com` address without issue.

I'm doing that by directly editing the `message`.

However, I still see these types of metadata when viewing the raw source of the email from the recipient's inbox (via Mozilla Thunderbird):

- `smtp.mailfrom=primary@example.com`
- `envelope-from=primary@example.com`

I cannot find any mention of how to select the alias address (`alias@example.com`) as the one that would appear in the above metadata.

I know it's *possible* because I can use the Thunderbird application to manually send an email from the same domain using the `alias@example.com` address the above metadata reflect that address as the sender.

I'm hoping there's a way simply do an equivalent of the following:

`service.users().messages().send(userId='me', body=message, sendAs(userId='alias@example.com')`

where the `sendAs` parameter (not valid syntax) would specify the sender as being the alias.

Note: the above works fine without the `sendAs` parameter; it just reflects the primary account email (the oned used for authentication) as the origin in some metadata.

References:

- GMail Messages API: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send
- GMail SendAs API: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs

Comment: Why don't you send using the secondary address directly instead of using a "primary" gmail address as a proxy? Thunderbird is probably doing that.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. I can't authenticate with an alias and even when I `sendAs` the alias the primary account still shows in the smtp meta.

Comment: Quite the interesting question. To be honest I have no experience with the Gmail API, however I will give you what I think after doing some minor reading. At first I would think what you are trying to do is not possible, since you are authenticating to the SMTP server with the `primary@example.com`, so it is normal that the SMTP meta will contain the primary email. However you say that this can be done with Thunderbird. 

Have you tried setting the boolean `treatAsAlias` to `false` in the SendAs API? This would be my first intuition.